# selenium - wait for scrolldown

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to automate downloads from a webpage using `selenium`.

So far my strategy is to instantiate a firefox driver that loads the page and clicks the download button. However, to be clickable, the button needs to be visible, i.e. not covered by any banners on the page (at least in my understanding). Therefore I need to scroll down (I use `scrollIntoView()`). If I run `button.click()` immediately after scrolling down, the download doesn't start, if I hard code a sufficient timeout in between it works out fine. Can somebody help me to set a timeout conditioned on the scroll down?

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

profilePath = '/path/to/my/firefox/profile'
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profilePath) 

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

driver.get("https://www.happyscribe.com/public/lex-fridman-podcast-artificial-intelligence-ai/164-andrew-huberman-sleep-dreams-creativity-the-limits-of-the-human-mind")

button = driver.find_element_by_id('btn-download')
target=driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: 'center'});", button)

time.sleep(10)

button.click()
```

and this is the html code of the button:

```
<button class="hs-btn-secondary small" id="btn-download" type="button">Download</button>
```

I would be very thankful for any direct help or suggestions on how to tackle the problem from a different angle.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may need to induce `WebDriverWait` for the element to by clickable. You could do so like this. It will wait for the element to be both `visible` and `enabled` before clicking.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

profilePath = '/path/to/my/firefox/profile'
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profilePath) 

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

driver.get("https://www.happyscribe.com/public/lex-fridman-podcast-artificial-intelligence-ai/164-andrew-huberman-sleep-dreams-creativity-the-limits-of-the-human-mind")

button = driver.find_element_by_id('btn-download')
target=driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: 'center'});", button)

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(button))

button.click()
```

Comment: Thanks. Your implementation throws this error:
```TypeError: selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element() argument after * must be an iterable, not FirefoxWebElement```

I adapted the second last line to the following:
```WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"btn-download")))```

Unfortunately that still doesn't do the trick. The browser just opens, scrolls down but does not perform the click.

Comment: Hi, iam using the Chrome Browser and it works perfectly,                                                      button = driver.find_element_by_id('btn-download')
target=driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: 'center'});", button)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'btn-download')))
button.click()

Comment: Great, thanks, now it works for me! If you repost it as an answer I can accept it.